# Detect when player has finished loading source after a new currentTime is set in videojs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

In my application, I have implemented a simple seeker UI which can change the `currentTime` of the currently playing media as follows:

```js
const seekEnd = (newPosition) => {
 const player = videojs(playerRef.current);
 player.currentTime(mediaDuration * (newPosition / 100));

 //some time passes before the media can resume playing if that part of the 
 //media is not loaded yet
}
```

How do I catch when the player has finished loading the portion of the media it needs to play from the newly set position?

I thought that `loadeddata` event would fire when that happens, but this only seems to fire when data is initially loaded for new media, and not when jumping to a new place in a media that the player has started playing already.

Answer (score 0):

With the [`canplaythrough`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event) event you can check whenever the video has enough data buffered to start playing the video without interruptions. And it also fires the event whenever you change position of the seeker and it has to get the data to play that video from that position.

```js
player.addEventListener('canplaythrough', event => {
  // I have downloaded enough data to start playing.
});
```

Comment: canplaythrough event is fired when the user agent can play the media, AND estimates that enough data has been loaded to play the media up to its end without having to stop for further buffering of content. We can't be sure the whole video is downloaded.